# Create an airplay server nodejs

Tags: ios, node.js

I am creating an airplay server with this documentation https://nto.github.io/AirPlay.html#screenmirroring

My code is the following one

```js
const airplay = require('airplay-server');
const macaddress = require('macaddress');
const express = require('express');

const http = express()

macaddress.one((err, mac) => {
  airplayServer = airplay({
    name: 'test',
    txt: {
      deviceid: mac,
      features: '0x5A7FFFF7',
      flags: '0x44',
      model: 'AppleTV3,2',
      srcvers: '220.68',
      vv: 2
    }
  })
  airplayServer.listen(7000);

  airplayServer.on('request', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Request received');
    console.log(req.method, req.url)
    console.log(req.headers)
  })

  airplayServer.on('listening', function () {
    console.log('Listen 7000');
  })
})

http.get('/stream.xml', (req, res) => {
  res.header("Content-Type", "text/x-apple-plist+xml");
  res.send('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"><plist version="1.0"><dict><key>height</key><integer>720</integer><key>overscanned</key><true/><key>refreshRate</key><real>0.016666666666666666</real><key>version</key><string>130.14</string><key>width</key><integer>1280</integer></dict></plist>')
});

http.post('/stream', ((req, res) => {
  console.log('STREAM !!!!!');
  res.end(200);
}))

http.listen(7100)
```

I have a server on 7000 and an other on 7100 to use the screen mirroring functionality of my phone

The `test` device appear when I am going in screen mirroring on my IPhone but I have the error message `Unable to connect to "test"`

The doc is quite old, can be outdated.

I receive nothing on post or request

Comment: Just for clarification: You are writing the `airplay-server` yourself, right? I did not find a package on npm that is initialized like yours. You might want to take a look at [this github repo](https://github.com/watson/airplay-protocol)

Comment: I am using the `airplay-server` package which is similar

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/airplay-server I think this is the package he is using! @Taxel

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and I had the same exact problem. I think the library (and the docs) you are using are way too old to catch up with the AirPlay Protocol. In the last four years, the protocol may have changed and also the airplay-server library you are using. I strongly recommend using a newer framework, I have been searching here: https://github.com/topics/airplay-server. Good luck!

Comment: I had a look to this list but no one seems to do what I need, I do not really understand why so few people investigate on that :D